# Mongodb change stream with pipeline using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, changestream

**I'm attempting to listen for changes in my mongodb cluster, using change streams; however after following several tutorials, my final implementation using mongoose doesn't work. How can I use the current mongoose connection to listen for changes in the database**

**mongoose connection:**

```
mongoose
.connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    // useCreateIndex: true
})
.then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB...");
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**Change stream:**

```
const pipeline = { 
  $match: {
    $or: [{ operationType: 'insert' },{ operationType: 'update' }], 
    'fullDocument.institution': uniId 
  } 
};

const changeStream = Post.watch([pipeline], {fullDocument: 'updateLookup'});

changeStream.on("change", next => {
        switch(next.operationType) {
          case 'insert':
            console.log('an insert happened...', "uni_ID: ", next.fullDocument.institution);
            let rooms = Object.keys(socket.rooms);
            console.log("rooms: ", rooms);

            nmsps.emit('insert', {
              type: 'insert',
              msg: 'New question available',
              newPost: next.fullDocument
            });
            break;

          case 'update':
            console.log('an update happened...');

            nmsps.emit('update', {
              type: 'update',
              postId: next.documentKey._id,
              updateInfo: next.updateDescription.updatedFields,
              msg: "Question has been updated."
            });
            break;

          case 'delete':
            console.log('a delete happened...');

            nmsps.emit('delete', {
              type: 'delete',
              deletedId: next.documentKey._id,
              msg: 'Question has been deleted.'
            });
            break;

          default:
            break;
       }
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

Because mongoose is using [mongodb driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) as the core module, you can use mongodb client to watch the change stream.

After connected:

```js
const client = mongoose.connection.client;
const db = client.db('dbName');
const collection = db.collection('collectionName');
const changeStream = collection.watch();
changeStream.on('change', next => {
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

He is a code of working solution with changeStream

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { connection } = require('../boot/mongo')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const status = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Number,
        required: true
    },
    receiveTs: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Date,
        required: true
    }
})

const OnlineStatusSchema = connection.model('Status', Status, 'status')

const pipeline = [
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [{ operationType: 'insert' }, { operationType: 'update' }]
        }
    },
    { $project: { 'fullDocument._id': 1, 'fullDocument.receiveTs': 1 } }
]



const changeStream = OnlineStatusSchema.watch(pipeline)

changeStream.on('change', async (change) => {
    // get meters reading log for respective platfrom and date
    try {
        console.log(change)
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
})

module.exports = OnlineStatusSchema
```

Comment: where is the close change stream section? please add it